# Confusion in floating-point modulus

Tags: java, c++, floating-point

I know C++ very well, but am a beginner in java.

#### Here are two tested programs:

The Java program gives output **3.2999997**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       float f = 9.9f, m = 3.3f;
       float c = f % m;
       System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

The C++ program gives output **8.88178e-16**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
   float f = 9.9f, m = 3.3f; 
   std::cout << fmod (9.9,3.3);
   return 0;
}
```

I am satisfied with the C++ program's output, but why is Java not giving an answer around zero?

How is this possible, since **3.3 * 3** = **9.9**

I know Java considers float's precision as 6-7 decimal digits, but I do not know how this output came? I researched this question on web, but did not find the logic behind this.

Comment: The Java program *is* giving an answer that is close to congruent with 0 (mod 3.3).

Comment: why not close to zero like c++?

Comment: It's just as close to 0 as the C++ program is (well, maybe not completely, but to a few decimal places).

Comment: please explain me in detail i am beginner in java and i am comparing the output with c++

Comment: This isn't about C++, it's just Math. In modulo 3.3, a bit over 0 is the same idea as a bit under 3.3. The bit under 3.3 is congruent to a bit under 0, but the range is restricted to [0, 3.3).

Comment: I know you already understand this, judging by the actual code in this question, but the modulus operator is only defined for integers in C++. Your title is slightly misleading as it implies you are literally talking about the modulus operator on floating-point numbers, not simply the fundamental operation it implements.

Comment: @Andon:but fmod() works for floating point also.it is included in c++ math library.while for integers % operator works fine

Comment: That is what I just told you, but your question's title speaks of the modulus ***operator***. `fmod (...)` is a function in the C standard library, not an operator.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: hope it's fine now?

Comment: @Prashant: Your edit actually caused the question to lose meaning, I went ahead and made a few additional edits for you.

Comment: @Andon:thanks you were right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java program is using `float`s.  But the C++ program is declaring `float`s and using what I assume are `double` floating point literals.

In your Java program I get `3.2999997` also, but when I change to `double`s, the output matches your C++ program's output: `8.881784197001252E-16` ([demo](http://ideone.com/64Fnv1)).

Either way, you're off from the true mathematical value of `0` because of floating-point numbers in both languages can be inexact.  The `float` values must be a little more inaccurate because they are more imprecise, hence a different value, a little less than 3.3.

Comment: `float`s get implicitly converted to `double`s during the call of `fmod`, which takes arguments of type `double`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Good point, though `double`s are still being passed in.

Comment: "The float values must be a little more inaccurate because they are more imprecise, hence a different value, a little less than 3.3"
does this impreciseness is because java considers float's precision as 6-7 decimal digits?

Comment: Java's `float` is a IEEE float, with 24 bits of precision (23 actual bits plus one implied `1` bit).  Its `double` is 53 bits of precision (52 actual bits plus one implied `1` bit).  If I remember correctly, C++ `double`s are also IEEE, which explains why the output is the same if `double`s are used in Java too.

Comment: **3.3** and **9.9** are not representable using a finite number of bits of mantissa (they are repeating numbers in base-2). To get exactly **0.0** from this, the compiler would have to look at those constants and replace that expression with some constant evaluated without floating-point. This is why you should not use direct floating-point comparison, most numbers you deal with in real-life cannot be represented precisely in floating-point. A usual test for floating-point "equality" actually requires +/- some small number to account for this.

Comment: In other words, switching from single-precision to double-precision in this case will not really help anything. Both precisions are limited in terms of mantissa, so neither can represent **3.3** or **9.9** accurately enough to produce exactly **0.0**.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman It's correct that neither can represent 3.3 or 9.9 accurately enough.  However, the `double` type is more precise, so you get values closer to the actual mathematical value than with `float`, for both the literals and the calculated values.  It does help.

Comment: Ah, okay. I misread your answer, sorry. A result from floating-point modulus consistent with mathematical mod in this case is going to be within [**0.0**, **epsilon**] or [**3.3 - epsilon**, **3.3**). The only real difference between the two is that `epsilon` is smaller for double-precision. You still basically have to test both ends of that if you are looking for equality with a particular modulo group.